# Usetex in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, latex

When I try to obtain plots in which the axis (both formulae and text) are written in LaTeX standard roman font, I keep not obtaining the plot, but the code runs without warnings. In particular, this simple scatter with TeX code in the axis labels, in which I have put my better understanding of the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.random.rand(100,1)

plt.rc('text', usetex=True) 
plt.rc('font', family='roman')
plt.scatter(x, y, c='b', s=10)
plt.xlabel(r'$\lambda$ ($\AA$)',size='12')
plt.ylabel(r'$F_\alpha (W/m^2)$ ',size='12')
plt.title(r'A title in \LaTeX typography')
plt.show()
```

keeps yielding a message like `<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1f75d4750>`, which I have met before, but I keep failing when trying to remedy this one. In addition, saving the plot (png or pdf) would not solve the issue, and if the problem is related to TeX, I have definitely not found any resource that can help. I use MacOS Sierra.

Comment: Unable to duplicate the problem.  Do you have all the dependencies (Latex, dvipng, and ghostscript) listed on the doc page you linked to, and are they in your path?  In other words, if you just open a terminal and type `dvipng`, what happens?  And are you sure there's no error-like output in your terminal?  I had to install a tex package and dvipng to get this to work, and discovered so due to error messages after calling plt.show.

Comment: Yes, I manually double-checked these installations. Typing `dvipng' it returns: `This is dvipng (dvipng (TeX Live)) 1.15 Copyright 2002-2015 Jan-Ake Larsson`. The problem is that I actually do not get an error, but the recurrent message `<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 01x...`. It looked like a have to 'retrieve' this figure from somewhere... However, I am not sure if the path is set correct, how do I access to it?

Comment: And you're calling `plt.show()` and nothing happens?

Comment: Correct, with the code shown above, just `<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 01x...>` is showed. Not even saving to pdf or png, it returns a blank file.